# ImageView stopped showing image

Tags: android, image, imageview

`ImageView` suddenly stopped showing image. It was showing image and then suddenly it stopped showing image(Not sure what i did)

> Here is how its look in Design view

[image]

> Image exists in res/drawable

[image]

> ImageView Tag

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

I have tried clean project still not resolve. Design view doesn't show any rendering errors

Comment: Is this a device specific or general behaviour?

Comment: Restarting android studio fixed the issue. Still don't what actually happen

Comment: This shall be a studio bug then.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `background.png` from the `drawable-xhdpi` folder and into the regular `drawable` folder. That looks like the error to me. You can try doing it in Windows Explorer if it is hard in Android Studio. Just look through the project files.